# Compile TailwindCSS to CSS

Tags: code-golf, string, css

[TailwindCSS](https://tailwindcss.com) is a utility that lets one write CSS code using only HTML classes, which are then converted to CSS code with the Tailwind compiler. Ordinarily, one would write CSS in a separate file from the HTML, and reference named classes:

```html
<!-- without Tailwind -->
<p class="crazy-monologue">Crazy? I was crazy once. They locked me in a room…</p>
```

```css
.crazy-monologue {
  background: black;
  color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

With Tailwind, the CSS is auto-generated:

```html
<!-- with Tailwind -->
<p class="background-[black] color-[red] opacity-[0.5]">
  Crazy? I was crazy once. They locked me in a room…
</p>
```

```css
/* auto-generated by Tailwind */
.background-\[black\]{background:black;}
.color-\[red\]{color:red;}
.opacity-\[0\.5\]{opacity:0.5;}
```

This is a simplified version of Tailwind; for the purposes of this challenge, all class names will be in the format `property-name-[value]`. The property name will be a `kebab-case` string, and the value will be an string consisting of alphanumeric characters and the period `.`. Note that the brackets `[` and `]` must be escaped as `\[` and `\]` in the outputted CSS selector, and the period `.` must be escaped as `\.`.

### Task

Given a class name in the above format, output the corresponding CSS. The CSS output is flexible; you may have any amount of whitespace before and after the curly braces and colons, and the semicolon is optional.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest answer in each language wins.

### Test cases

Note that since the CSS output is flexible, your output does not have to be formatted exactly as these are.

```css
/* in: opacity-[0.5] */
/* out: */
.opacity-\[0\.5\] { opacity: 0.5 }

/* in: background-color-[lightgoldenrodyellow] */
/* out: */
.background-color-\[lightgoldenrodyellow\] {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}
```

Comment: Will input have multiple properties, like in your main text example?

Comment: @bigyihsuan The input will be a single class name.

Comment: A hypothetical regex extension I came up with for the purpose of this challenge, 40 bytes: `(\i)-\[(.+)]/$1-\\\[($2/[.-]/\\$3)]{$1:$2}`. May write up an answer after I implement it

Comment: Side note: been using https://unocss.dev/ as an alternative engine to Tailwind - it's quite nice

Comment: Also worth pointing out that while tailwind _allows_ arbitrary values with the bracket syntax, that's not really how it's _meant_ to be used for the most part.

Comment: @Cubic Yeah, I wanted to make it a simple challenge so I didn't include the whole Tailwind syntax.

Answer (score 6):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 236 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 29.5 bytes

```
\-/÷₍λ\.øBf:\\vpĿ;‡ḢṪMf`%-%{%:%}`$%
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJBPSIsIiIsIlxcLS/Dt+KCjc67XFwuw7hCZjpcXFxcdnDEvzvigKHhuKLhuapNZmAlLSV7JTolfWAkJSIsIiIsIm9wYWNpdHktWzAuNV1cbmJhY2tncm91bmQtY29sb3ItW2xpZ2h0Z29sZGVucm9keWVsbG93XVxuYmFja2dyb3VuZC1bYmxhY2tdXG5jb2xvci1bcmVkXVxuYW1vbmctW3VzXSJd)

Truly among sus.

"But lyxal what does that have to do with the challenge?"

Nothing. That's just how golfing at 11:52pm be like.

### Explained

```
\-/÷₍λ\.øBf:\\vpĿ;‡ḢṪMf`%-%{%:%}`$%­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
\-/÷                                 # ‎⁡Split input on '-' and dump
    ₍λ           ;‡                  # ‎⁢Parallel apply the following:
                                     # ‎⁢
      \.øBf:\\vpĿ                    # ‎⁣  Escape '[', '.' and ']'
                   ḢṪ                # ‎⁤  Remove the square brackets
                     M               # ‎⁢⁡Prepend the property to each
                      f              # ‎⁢⁢And flatten
                                 $%  # ‎⁢⁣Formatting into the string
                       `%-%{%:%}`    # ‎⁢⁤"%-%{%:%}"
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: +1 for "That's just how golfing at 11:52pm be like."

Comment: +1 for HTM in the code

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 67 bytes

```python
import re
lambda x:f'.{re.escape(x)}{{{x.replace("-[",":")[:-1]}}}'
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXMSc5NSEhUqrNLU9aqLUvVSi5MTC1I1KjRrq6urK_SKUgtyEpNTNZR0o5V0lKyUNKOtdA1ja2tr1bkycwvyi0oUilKhRlkUFGXmlWikaagnJSZnpxfll-al6EYnAbVnx6pranLBpfMLEpMzSyp1ow30TEEyEP0LFkBoAA)

The "-" is also escaped, but that's still legal CSS.

Comment: FYI, you can put the import after the lambda definition so you can have the `f=` in the ATO header: [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3nXMSc5NSEhUqrNLU9aqLUvVSi5MTC1I1KjRrq6urK_SKUgtyEpNTNZR0o5V0lKyUNKOtdA1ja2tr1bkycwvyi0oUilKhRlkUFGXmlWikaagnJSZnpxfll-al6EYnAbVnx6pranLBpfMLEpMzSyp1ow30TEEyEP0LFkBoAA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
-\[(.+)]
$&{$`:$1}
\W(?=.*{)
\$&
^
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7wXzcmWkNPWzOWS0WtWiXBSsWwlismXMPeVk@rWpMrRkWNK45L7///pMTk7PSi/NK8FN3k/Jz8It3opBygUCwXlFeUmhLLlV@QmJxZUqkbbaBnGsuFqSUnMz2jJD0/JyU1ryg/pTI1Jye/PBYA) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
-\[(.+)]
$&{$`:$1}
```

Append the CSS declaration block.

```
\W(?=.*{)
\$&
```

Escape non-word characters in the class name.

```
^
.
```

Prefix the `.` class selector.

Edit: Saved 1 byte thanks to @noodleman pointing out that the `;` is optional. 41 bytes to include the `;` and not escape `-`s:

```
-\[(.+)]
$&{$`:$1;}
[^-\w](?=.*{)
\$&
^
.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZcvBCgIhFEDR/fsOG5xCqUWbIlr2EeowjopJD1@IMQxD324t2rW8B24JNWXbNvw2NqEVl7veAOtWNp7Y4fwGNQg9G369yO3ag2YdDCBbm6x7xEKv7IUjpCLUhF8y8KsSvAF6WpfqItReHg38L5jivUZCH3IhvwREms0H) Link includes test cases.

29 bytes in [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language) 1.0:

```
((.+)-\[(.+))]
.$\$1\]{$2:$3}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYvLCsMgEADvfoeHhKDkQS/9Fd2DUTHSxS2LpYTQb7cN9JbTMAPDsebipta6Tg@9suZED0JLKycLh5zvcvm0tjr/SEyvEpQnJFZmxV8C8TeOAQQ9nc91V2bUNxDXBXPaaiIMsTCFPSLSG74) Link includes test cases. Explanation: `$\` quotes `.` and `[` characters in its argument, but the `]` needs to be quoted manually.

Comment: The semicolon is optional so you can remove it to save a byte.

Comment: @noodleman Thanks for pointing that out, I had overlooked that.

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 68 bytes

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/[[\].]/g,"\\$&")+`{${[a,b]=s.split(/-\[|\]/),a}:${b}}`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcvBCsIgGADge48hIyZN7dIlWC@iwpwzW/34i1ox1p7d6Nr547ubl8k2zbGwgJOr177m/pJ5chGMda2QUmmuhe@IUs2e0MOwNqs03aj7zHOEubSCKflRWtDObOdmHbdtqBZDRnAc0LfXlmA0di4Lk0d@0oTS3Z@Pxj58wmeYmEXAxCTM/lY8wuRCwmlxAPj@zfoF)

Comment: You seem to have a surplus `:` at the beginning of your template string.

Comment: @Neil Good catch. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-pl`, 44 bytes

After a lot of optimization it effectively became SuperStormer's Python solution.

```ruby
$_=".#{Regexp.escape$_}{#{sub'-[',?:;chop}}"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcnm0km5BjlLsgqWlJWm6Fjd1VOJtlfSUq4NS01MrCvRSi5MTC1JV4murlauLS5PUdaPVdeytrJMz8gtqa5UgeqBaF9w0zS9ITM4sqdSNNtAzjeVKSkzOTi_KL81L0U3Oz8kv0o3OyUzPKEnPz0lJzSvKT6lMzcnJL4-F6AYA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 34 bytes

```
≔⪪⁻Ｓ]¦-[θ.§θ⁰-\[⪫⪪§θ¹.¦\.¦\]{⪫θ:¦}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/9@xuDgzPU8juCAns0TDNzOvtFjDM6@gtCS4pCgzL11DU0dBKVYJROpGg6hCTWuuAKBMiYaSnhKc7VjimZeSWqFRqKNgoIlQoRsTE41Q5JWfCbMHSb0hyGw9sA0xMUAaoTsmJrYaTTdQvZIVsppaoIL///MLEpMzSyp1ow30TGP/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
≔⪪⁻Ｓ]¦-[θ
```

Remove the trailing `]` from the input string, then split it on `-[`.

```
.
```

Output the CSS class selector.

```
§θ⁰
```

Output the property name.

```
-\[
```

Output the trailing `-` and the quoted opening `[`.

```
⪫⪪§θ¹.¦\.
```

Output the property value with `.`s quoted.

```
\]{
```

Output the quoted closing `]` and the opening `{` of the declaration block.

```
⪫θ:
```

Join the property and value into a declaration and output it.

```
}
```

Output the closing `}` of the declaration block.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 24 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
…]-[ā£':æ:…{ÿ}«„[]SD'\ì‡
```

Outputs without the optional `;` to save a byte.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcOyWN3oI42HFqtbHV5mBeRWH95fe2j1o4Z50bHBLuoxh9c8alj4/39SYnJ2elF@aV6KbnJ@Tn6RbnRSDlAoFgA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9TVmmvpPCobZKCkn2ly/9HDctidaOPNB5arG51eJkVkFt9eH/todWPGuZFxwa7qMccXvOoYeF/nf9JicnZ6UX5pXkputFJOUBOLFdyfk5@kW50UWpKLFd@QWJyZkmlbrSBnmksF5JiqKKczPSMkvT8nJTUvKL8lMrUnJz88liugqL8gtQioLa8xNxU3eiyxJzS1FgA).

**Explanation:**

```python
…]-[        # Push string "]-["
    ā       # Push a list in the range [1,length] (without popping): [1,2,3]
     £      # Split the string into parts of those sizes: ["]","-[",""]
      ':   '# Push ":"
        æ   # Pop and push its powerset: ["",":"]
         :  # Replace the values in the (implicit) input-string:
            #  All "]" are replaced with "", so basically removed
            #  And all "-[" are replaced with ":"
            #  (the trailing "" of the first list is ignored)
…{ÿ}        # Surround it with curly brackets
    «       # Append it to the (implicit) input-string
„[]S        # Push "[]" as a pair of characters: ["[","]"]
    D       # Duplicate it
     '\ì   '# Prepend an "\" in front of each: ["\[","\]"]
        ‡   # Transliterate all "[" to "\[" and "]" to "\]"
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 67 bytes

```scala
x=>s".${x.replaceAll("\\W","\\\\$0")}{${x.replace("-[",":").init}}"
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=VYwxCoNAFER7T_H5WChEESQQBAWTOlWKFJpiXVfZuKyLrsEgniSNTXInbxOJKZJmpngz7_FqKRHEn2a_zq6MajgSLoH1msm8hVgpGAzDuBEBRQAn3XBZhtHaED47XTi7-dCHUYuuOfRuw5QglMVCWJimZ9wsmaamh_Y4_HALnWRhAdoul1yPI35VewC1uLWQVmFhRmhVNnUncyfJll91Qds2_ia1IpTru5N47vZDx9U0TWu_AQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala 3](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 180 bytes

A port of [@SuperStormer's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264705/110802) in Scala.

---

```scala
x=>{val e=x.replaceAllLiterally("-","\\-").replaceAllLiterally("[","\\[").replaceAllLiterally("]","\\]").replaceAllLiterally(".","\\.");s".$e{${x.replace("-[",":").dropRight(1)}}"}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sODkxJ9F4wU3j_KSs1OQSBd_EzDyF1IqS1LyUYgXHggKFai4urrLEHIU0K4XgkqLMvHRbOwitYLu0tCRN1-Lmlgpbu2qQklTbCr2i1IKcxORUx5wcn8yS1KLEnJxKDSVdJR2lmBhdJU3s0tFg6Whc0rFg6Vhc0npgaT0lTetiJT2V1GqVargrgDaDzLYCak0pyi8IykzPKNEw1KytVaqFut1JQaEA6JmSnDyNNA2lpMTk7PSi_NK8FN3oJKAB2UBLNblQlOQXJCZnllTqRhvomYJloSYtWAChAQ)